# I am getting this error and can't map file list file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting this error and don't know what is the issue at all  Its suddenly started to coming up for all my projects when I compile it.

> /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   can't map file list file: /Users/aravindsekar/Desktop/Office/newPad/
>   (Invalid argument)

Its happen when I start to add pods in my project.

Note: I checked same kind of issue and its not helping me.  All my Target binaries are in active state and there is no issue there. Cleaned. Did Project clean as well.

In fact this is the complete error for one of the project

Libtool /Users/aravindsekar/Downloads/ElasticTransition-master/,/ElasticTransitionExample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods.framework/Pods normal x86_64
    cd /Users/aravindsekar/Downloads/ElasticTransition-master/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -L/Users/aravindsekar/Downloads/ElasticTransition-master/,/ElasticTransitionExample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/aravindsekar/Downloads/ElasticTransition-master/,/ElasticTransitionExample/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pods.LinkFileList -framework Foundation -o /Users/aravindsekar/Downloads/ElasticTransition-master/,/ElasticTransitionExample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods.framework/Pods

Comment: remove derived data

Comment: clear dervied data and clean and run once

Comment: I did that too as well. I am getting a folder getting created with ",". Not sure whether that is the root cause of the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Folder it is trying to create has space or special characters. I got this error when I was building Ionic app for iOS. It worked fine till the **name** tag in my config.xml did not have a coma character. Just to be doubly sure give it a one word name and then restart the build for ios.

1. cordova platform rm ios
2. cordova platform add ios
3. ionic cordova prepare ios
4. then build using xcode . 
   To open the project in Xcode you need to look for .xcodeproj. For ionic project it is in platforms > ios

Now click on the build icon, or from the Menu Product > Build